# Invalid window in DocumentComplete (DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE) in IE9 BHO

Tags: c++, events, internet-explorer-9, bho, mshtml

I'm developing the BHO and I have a problems with events handling in **IE9**.
I handle **DocumentComplete** (DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE), then I get **IHTMLWindow2** and its **IHTMLLocation** for future operations.

**Code (simplified)**

The BHO class uses

```c++
public IDispEventImpl<1, CBHO, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 0>,
```

Advising browsers events in **SetSite**

```c++
STDMETHODIMP CBHO::SetSite(IUnknown *punkSite)
{
    if(punkSite != NULL)
    {
        CComQIPtr<IServiceProvider> pServiceProvider = punkSite;
        pServiceProvider->QueryService(SID_SWebBrowserApp, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&m_pWebBrowser);
        IDispEventImpl<1, CBHO, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 0>::DispEventAdvise(m_pWebBrowser);
    }
...
}
```

Sink map

```c++
BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CBHO)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE, OnDownloadComplete)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_NAVIGATECOMPLETE2, OnNavigateComplete2)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_ONQUIT, OnQuit)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_WINDOWSTATECHANGED, OnWindowStateChanged)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_PROPERTYCHANGE, OnPropertyChange)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2, BeforeNavigate2)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, DocumentComplete)
END_SINK_MAP()
```

DocumentComplete event handler:

```c++
void _stdcall CBHO::DocumentComplete( IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *URL)
{
    CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> pBrowser(pDisp);
    CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispDoc;
    pBrowser->get_Document(&pDispDoc);
    CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pDoc(pDispDoc);;
    CComPtr<IHTMLWindow2> wnd;
    pDoc->get_parentWindow(&wnd);

    CComPtr<IHTMLLocation> pLoc;
    HRESULT hr = wnd->get_location(&pLoc);
    CComBSTR locHref; 
    hr=oLoc->get_href(&locHref);  //"Access denied" error here
}
```

This works correct in most cases, **except the opening link in new tab** (using middle click or links with target="_blank").
In this new-tab case I get DocumentComplete event, then get non-NULL wnd pointer to the IHTMLWindow2 and IHTMLLocation, but when I try any operation with pLoc pointer, such as getting href or anything else, I get "Access denied error" error.
Also, when check *doc.documentElement.outerHTML* I got

```c++
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>&nbsp;</P></BODY></HTML>
```

and this is not a content of target page.

At the same time in IE10 this code works as expected.

Could anybody please advise, where I am wrong and why I get invalid object in DocumentComplete?